# Counting the divs in a cell and adding styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cells

At the moment, I'm using a plugin for time tabling and it builds the time tables in to a table. As per the customer's request, they would like to be able to have two classes at the same time. To facilitate this, I need to count if a cell has two instances of a div in it. If the cell has two instances in it, styling would be applied to allow each one to take up half the space in the cell and float next to each other. At the moment, the best way to do this would seem to be with JQuery.

Here's an example of the table that's generated:

```
 <table>
        <tr>
          <th class="wcs3-ex1-hour-row-19-00">19:00</th>
          <td class="wcs3-cell wcs3-hour-row-19-00 wcs3-day-col-1 wcs3-abs-col-0">
            <div class="wcs3-ex1-td-relative">
              <div class="wcs3-class-container wcs3-ex1-cell-wrapper wcs3-ex1-19-00-20-00-1" style="height: 139.59375px;">
                <div class="wcs3-class-name">Piloxing</div>
                <div class="wcs3-details-box-container"><span class="wcs3-qtip-box"><a href="#qtip" class="wcs3-qtip" data-hasqtip="96">Piloxing</a><span class="wcs3-qtip-data">A muscle-toning, fat-burning cardio fusion that blends the power, speed &amp; agility of boxing with exhilarating dance moves and the targeted sculpting and flexibility of pilates to burn maximum calories, build lean muscle &amp; increase stamina, leaving you feeling physically &amp; mentally empowered.</span></span>


                  19:00 to 20:00</div>
                <div class="wcs3-ex1-bottom-border" style="height: 1px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wcs3-ex1-td-relative">
              <div class="wcs3-class-container wcs3-ex1-cell-wrapper wcs3-ex1-19-00-20-00-1" style="height: 139.59375px; background-color: rgb(0, 50, 199);">
                <div class="wcs3-class-name">Spinning</div>
                <div class="wcs3-details-box-container"><span class="wcs3-qtip-box"><a href="#qtip" class="wcs3-qtip" data-hasqtip="97">Spinning</a><span class="wcs3-qtip-data">Using indoor stationary bikes, class participants will experience a fun, challenging &amp; exhilarating workout. The instructor will lead and motivate you through a series of phases on your bike but you can control the intensity at which you work.</span></span>


                  19:00 to 20:00</div>
                <div class="wcs3-ex1-bottom-border" style="height: 1px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="wcs3-cell wcs3-hour-row-19-00 wcs3-day-col-2 wcs3-abs-col-1">
            <div class="wcs3-ex1-td-relative">
              <div class="wcs3-class-container wcs3-ex1-cell-wrapper wcs3-ex1-19-00-20-00-2" style="height: 139.59375px;">
                <div class="wcs3-class-name">SalsaTone</div>
                <div class="wcs3-details-box-container"><span class="wcs3-qtip-box"><a href="#qtip" class="wcs3-qtip" data-hasqtip="98">SalsaTone</a><span class="wcs3-qtip-data">A dance fitness workout that uses steps from the salsa, cha cha &amp; samba, fused with aerobic moves to improve cardiovascular fitness as well as toning your whole body.</span></span>


                  19:00 to 20:00</div>
                <div class="wcs3-ex1-bottom-border" style="height: 1px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="wcs3-cell wcs3-hour-row-19-00 wcs3-day-col-3 wcs3-abs-col-2">
            <div class="wcs3-ex1-td-relative">
              <div class="wcs3-class-container wcs3-ex1-cell-wrapper wcs3-ex1-19-00-20-00-3" style="height: 139.59375px; background-color: rgb(0, 50, 199);">
                <div class="wcs3-class-name">Spinning</div>
                <div class="wcs3-details-box-container"><span class="wcs3-qtip-box"><a href="#qtip" class="wcs3-qtip" data-hasqtip="99">Spinning</a><span class="wcs3-qtip-data">Using indoor stationary bikes, class participants will experience a fun, challenging &amp; exhilarating workout. The instructor will lead and motivate you through a series of phases on your bike but you can control the intensity at which you work.</span></span>


                  19:00 to 20:00</div>
                <div class="wcs3-ex1-bottom-border" style="height: 1px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          </table>
```

And here is the JQuery that I thought would count inside each cell and if the count of divs with the marked class was greater than 1 it would apply styling to the divs inside that cell:

```
$(".wcs3-cell").each(function() {
  var n = $("tbody > tr > td > div.wcs3-ex1-td-relative > div.wcs3-class-name").length;
  if (n > 1) {
        //alert('boom')
    $("div.wcs3-ex1-td-relative").css("background", "yellow");
    } 
    else {
    //alert('boom')
        $("div.wcs3-ex1-td-relative").css("background", "orange");
    }
});
```

At the moment, all this returns is is making all the divs orange. 
Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: check your html its buggy

Comment: you are missing `</tr>` closing tag, its working fine at my end

Comment: besides the missing `</tr>`  your table has 3 columns ( `<td>`) but you only have one header cell  (`<th>`)

Comment: Hi Guys, My bad for not posting the whole table, it's a bit big and didn't want to overload the question. Dekkard's jquery has done the job though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".wcs3-cell").each(function() {
    var n = $(this).find("div.wcs3-class-name").length;
    if (n > 1) {
        $(this).find("div.wcs3-ex1-td-relative").css("background", "yellow");
    } 
    else {
        $(this).find("div.wcs3-ex1-td-relative").css("background", "orange");
    }
});
```